# How to find the derivative of the function at $0$

Tags: real-analysis

> How to find the derivative of the function at $0$
>
> $f(x)=e^{-\frac{1}{x^2}}\sin\frac{1}{x}$ if $x\ne0$
>
> $=0$ if $x=0$

I cannnot evaluate the limit $$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{e^{-\frac{1}{x^2}}\sin\frac{1}{x}}{x}.$$

L'Hospital is not working here.

Please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint 1: $-1\le \sin(1/x)\le 1$.

Hint 2: $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1}{x}e^{-1/x^2} = \lim_{y\to \pm\infty} y\cdot e^{-y^2}$.

Comment: I have tried this but could not solve yet the rest of the limit.

Answer (score 2):

You already know that $|\sin(1/x)|\le 1$. This helps you only if the rest is $0$. So do a change of variable $y=1/x$ and use $e^{-\frac 1{x^2}}=\frac 1 {e^{y^2}}$. Now you need to calculate $$\lim_{y\to\pm\infty}\frac y{e^{y^2}}$$

Answer (score 1):

$-1\le \sin(1/x)\le 1 \:\:\text{and let $\frac1x=t$}\implies -\dfrac{t}{e^{t^2}}\leq \sin t\dfrac{t} {e^{t^2}} \leq \dfrac{t}{e^{t^2}}$ Taking limit as $t\rightarrow \infty$ and using L'hopital rule we get $\displaystyle \lim_{t\rightarrow\infty}\sin t\dfrac{t} {e^{t^2}}=0$.